# Vuejs v-for error remove element firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

```js
<tr v-for="(unfilm) in film" v-bind:key="unfilm.key">
 
   <td>
                      <div id="titolo">{{unfilm.titolo}}</div>
    </td>
 
    <td>
                                <img :src="unfilm.locandina" style="max-width: 50px;">
       </td>
    
     <i @click="cancellaFilm(unfilm)" class="material-icons deep-orange-text text-darken-4"
            style="cursor: pointer;">delete</i></td>
   
   
   cancellaFilm(unfilm) {
     gamesRef.child(unfilm['.key']).remove()
     
      this.$toastr.info('Errore', 'Attenzione');
          //  this.$alert("Film cancellato")
        }
  }
```

When i clicked button "cancellaFilm" , returned error like:

[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "undefined".
  Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]""

In Cdn mode it works in mpm mode it does not work. I tried to test the problem seems to be due to the macacato passage of the "unfilm" object
What should I modify?

below list the versions of the used packages:

"bootstrap-vue": "^2.13.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "firebase": "^7.14.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.0.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-simple-alert": "^1.1.1",
    "vue-toastr-2": "0.0.10",
    "vuefire": "^2.2.2"

[image: lost_list]

Comment: show a piece of a template where 'gamesRef' is defined

Answer (score 0):

In your `cancellaFilm()` function, `unfilm['.key']` is `undefined`.

Do

```
gamesRef.child(unfilm['key']).remove()
```

instead.

Comment: yes here: export default {
  firebase: {
    film: gamesRef,
   
  }

Answer (score 0):

I insert the remaining data code:

```js
import {gamesRef} from './firebase'


export default {
  firebase: {
    film: gamesRef,
   
  }
```

In firebase.js

```js
import Firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/database'

const app = Firebase.initializeApp({
 //configuration data
})  
export var db = app.database();
export var gamesRef = db.ref('altro')
```

```js
add_film() {
   
   gamesRef.push(this.nuovoFilm);
   }
```

Is the problem due to the vu js version or the firebase version? What should I change? can you make an example or fix the code?
Thanks a lot